# How to Add NAV odata webservice dynamically through code

Tags: c#, odata, dynamics-nav

I have added the odata webservice reference using the Add Service Reference option from visual studio. But client suggesting us to do that through coding by having the url in web.config.

In future if they has to switch to different url then it will be easy for them to add it .

Answer (score 0):

That is easy enough to do.

You just keep your Service Reference because it contains the contract of the service. You can store the URL in your config file.

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="ServiceURL" value="http://somewhere.com/Service" />
</appSettings>
```

and before you call the service, modify its URL by

```
reference.Endpoint.Address = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceURL"];
```

Comment: ok. I need to invoke web service itself at runtime. For now i am adding service reference manually in visual studio using Add service Reference option from solution explorer.

Comment: Yes, of course. You add the Service Reference at development time, you instantiate it at runtime and before you call it, you modify its `Endpoint.Address` property as in the example above.